# Google contacts import using oauth2.0

Tags: python, google-api, oauth-2.0, contacts, google-api-python-client

What possible ways to import google contacts using python and **oauth2.0** exists?

We successfully got credentials, and our application requests access to contacts, but after getting credentials I can't find way to discover contacts api.

So things like:

```
 from apiclient.discover import build
 import httplib2
 http = httplib2.Http()
 #Authorization
 service = build("contacts", "v3", http=http)
```

Gives us `UnknownApiNameOrVersion` exception. 
It looks like Contacts API not in list of supported APIs for apiclient.

I'm looking for alternative ways.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) can't be used with the `google-api-python-client` library because it is a [Google Data API](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference), while `google-api-python-client` is intended to be used with [discovery-based APIs](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/getting_started#background).

Rather than going through all the trouble described by [@NikolayFominyh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/656804/nikolay-fominyh), you can use the native support for OAuth 2.0 in `gdata-python-client`.

To get a valid token, follow the instructions from a Google Developers [blog post](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/09/python-oauth-20-google-data-apis.html) for an in-depth description of the process.

### First, create a token object:

```
import gdata.gauth

CLIENT_ID = 'bogus.id'  # Provided in the APIs console
CLIENT_SECRET = 'SeCr3Tv4lu3'  # Provided in the APIs console
SCOPE = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
USER_AGENT = 'dummy-sample'

auth_token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
    scope=SCOPE, user_agent=USER_AGENT)
```

### Then, authorize your application with this token:

```
APPLICATION_REDIRECT_URI = 'http://www.example.com/oauth2callback'
authorize_url = auth_token.generate_authorize_url(
    redirect_uri=APPLICATION_REDIRECT_URI)
```

After generating this `authorize_url`, you (or users of your application) will need to visit it and accept the OAuth 2.0 prompt. If this is within a web application, you can simply redirect, otherwise you'll need to visit the link in a browser.

### After authorizing, exchange the code for a token:

```
import atom.http_core

redirect_url = 'http://www.example.com/oauth2callback?code=SOME-RETURNED-VALUE'
url = atom.http_core.ParseUri(redirect_url)
auth_token.get_access_token(url.query)
```

In the case you visited a browser, you'll need to copy the URL you were redirected to into the variable `redirect_url`.

In the case you are in a web application, you will be able to specify the handler for the path `/oauth2callback` (for example) and simply can retrieve the query parameter `code` to exchange the code for a token. For example, if using `WebOb`:

```
redirect_url = atom.http_core.Uri.parse_uri(self.request.uri)
```

### Finally authorize your client with this token:

```
import gdata.contacts.service

client = gdata.contacts.service.ContactsService(source='appname')
auth_token.authorize(client)
```

### Update (12+ months after original answer):

Alternately you can use the `google-api-python-client` support as I describe in a [blog post](http://blog.bossylobster.com/2012/12/bridging-oauth-20-objects-between-gdata.html).

Comment: Great! That's what I was looking for, when was asking this question!

Comment: In my redirect handler view "oauth2callback" I cannot access the auth_token object which was created in the initial view. Do you know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Final solution was relatively easy.

**Step 1**
Obtain oauth2.0 token. It's pretty documented in official docs:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/OAuth2

**Step 2** 
Now we have token, but can not discover contacts API. 
But you can find, that in oauth2.0 playground you can import contacts. 
https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/

You can find, that you have access token in credentials, obtained in Step 1. 
To access contacts api you must add to headers following param `'Authorization':'OAuth %s' % access_token`

**Step 3**
Now you must pass to google library token, that will be compatible with oauth1.0 token. 
It can be done by following code:

```
from atom.http import ProxiedHttpClient #Google contacts use this client
class OAuth2Token(object):
    def __init__(self, access_token):
        self.access_token=access_token

    def perform_request(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url = 'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full'
        http = ProxiedHttpClient()
        return http.request(
            'GET',
            url,
            headers={
                'Authorization':'OAuth %s' % self.access_token
            }
        )
google = gdata.contacts.service.ContactsService(source='appname')
google.current_token = OAuth2Token(oauth2creds.access_token)
feed = google.GetContactsFeed()
```